# Gitbook remote not rendering maths in reading mode

Tags: github, gitbook, katex

I'm writing up a Gitbook and there's some maths involved. Great, given there's [KateX support](https://www.gitbook.com/blog/features/katex)!

With the *Gitbook Editor*, all is fine, maths get rendered alright, as can be seen here

[image: on Gitub Editor]

Same for when I'm on the remote repo and I use the *editor* mode.

But, on the *reading* mode in remote, I get this instead

[image: in the reading mode remote]

I've tried seen if by any means some plugin had to be chosen in the settings, but nothing.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added `"plugins": ["katex"]` to your `book.json` file?

Rendering will work in the editor even if you haven't added it.

If you haven't made or edited a `book.json` file, add one in your book's root directory, and put the following in it:

```
{
    "plugins": ["katex"]
}
```